# How to approve new articles and edits in Mediawiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

When users create or edit articles I want to approve them first and then publish them. How can I achieve that or What extension make this possible?

Comment: I can change my version to what is capable of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [FlaggedRevs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FlaggedRevs) extension. It adds a status to each article, the status can change when the article is edited (based on the permissions of the editor), and certain user groups can change the status by hand. You can use the status to hide the article from readers or show them the last approved state. The extension is used in several Wikimedia projects so it is reliably maintained. Its main disadvantage is that it is very flexible and has way more options than you need (it supports multiple levels of "approvedness", multiple approval dimensions, complex rules on when to show which version among other things), so configuring it is a bit complicated. (It took me quite a while to figure it out back in 2007; by now there might be good tutorials around, I don't know.)