# Is there a MediaWiki extension that queues articles for admin approval?

Tags: mediawiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to approve new articles and edits in Mediawiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017440/how-to-approve-new-articles-and-edits-in-mediawiki)

I want to restrict the article creation in my MediaWiki site. If a user is writing an article, it will not be published immediately instead it will sit in a queue for Admin approval. Any extension available to do this?

Comment: Yeah .. Thanks.. I got the answer now :)